# Animate one background-image out of many background-images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have implemented 2 background images in CSS to get the blend mode style as per Photoshop layout. And I got that right too. But now i want to animate only one image out of those.

```
.home
    background:
      image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZDsP.jpg), url(https://img.clipartfest.com/d840c9cfc1786dc7013443ac7638dde0_halloween-clip-art-free-spider-spider-web-clipart-png_500-463.png)
      blend-mode: color-dodge
      repeat: no-repeat
      size: cover, contain
      position: 0, center
    height: 100vh
```

Do you guys have any idea how to that?

check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/thanoosh/pen/xgbqMj). I want to rotate infinite animation for the foreground image (spider web)

Answer (score 0):

Just define another class assign to new `<div>` in your `<section>`

Try this.

```
<section class="home">
    <div class="rotating"></div>
</section>
```

Define this css

```
/* rotation animation */
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); }
  to { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  from { -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); }
  to { -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}

@-ms-keyframes rotate {
  from { -ms-transform:rotate(0deg); }
  to { -ms-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes rotate {
  from { -o-transform:rotate(0deg); }
  to { -o-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}

.rotating {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image: url(https://img.clipartfest.com/d840c9cfc1786dc7013443ac7638dde0_halloween-clip-art-free-spider-spider-web-clipart-png_500-463.png);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation-name: rotate;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-animation-name: rotate;
  -ms-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-animation-name: rotate;
  -o-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Hope it Helps

Comment: i think you didn't get my question well.. What i need is i want to add animation for one of the background image without effecting background-blend-mode style.. I updated the [codepen](http://codepen.io/thanoosh/pen/xgbqMj) link check that out.. then you will get the idea.